# ¿Cómo copio los valores de un array en otro invertido?

Tags: java, array

Con invertido me refiero a que los valores se guarden al revés. Ejemplo:

```
Array1: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.
Array2: 9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1.
```

He hecho esto:

```
int[] array1 = new int[10];      //Crear arrays
int[] array2 = new int [10];



int i = 0;                      //Introducir valores desde teclado
while(i < array1.length){
    array1[i] = in.nextInt();
    i++;
}



    int p = 0;                    //Copiar valores de array1 a array2
    int v = array2.length;
    while(p < v){
        array2[v] = array1[p];
        
        v--;
        p++;
    }
```

Y me da este error después de introducir los valores:

> Command execution failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException:
> Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) Failed to execute goal
> org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (default-cli) on
> project Arrays: Command execution failed. Process exited with an
> error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1] To see the full stack trace of
> the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. Re-run Maven using the -X
> switch to enable full debug logging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema que te está dando, es que te sales de los límites del array al recorrerlo para asignarlo al revés. Pero como no estás lanzando el programa con la depuración completa, no ves el *stack trace* completo. Tal como te dice en el error: **To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.**

Pero ahora vamos con el error en si:

```
//Array hardcodeado para evitarme introducirlo cada vez
    int[] array1 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    int[] array2 = new int [10];

    /* Este era tu código, aquí veo un error gordo en la lógica del while, pero además...
     * veo problemas con los nombres de las variables. Jamás uses nombres como p, v, x, y... no tienen sentido.
     * Te llevaría apenas dos segundos más usar nombres explicativos y cuando alguien lea tu código, no tiene
     * que andar revisando qué carajo eran P y V!
     */
//        int p = 0;
//        int v = array2.length;
//        while(p < v){
//            array2[v] = array1[p];
//
//            v--;
//            p++;
//        }
    // Así que vamos a reescribir ese loop pero más ... legible
    int index = array1.length -1;
    /* Empezamos declarando la variable que usaremos para recorrer el array con el valor más grande que puede tener,
     * que en este caso es la longitud del array menos uno. Menos uno porque los array empiezan por 0, no por 1!
     * Por qué? Porque quieres recorrerlo al revés, no? Pues entonces directamente empezamos por el final y
     * acabamos cuando lleguemos al 0!
     */
    while(index >= 0){
        /* En vez de usar una segunda variable para ir recorriendo positivamente, podemos obtener el
         * índice *creciente* simplemente restando la longitud del array menos el valor actual de index, eso si,
         * restándole uno para compensar que el valor de array1.length es 10 y no 9, ya que necesitamos
         * que el valor empiece por 0, no por 1!
         */
        array2[array1.length - index -1] = array1[index];
        index--;
    }

    // Imprimo el array para ver el resultado
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array2));
```

---

Te he dejado la explicación de todos los cambios en comentarios, para cualquier duda aquí estamos.

Comment: La mejor manera de agradecer es marcar la respuesta como *aceptada*. Además así ayudas a otra gente que pueda tener una duda similar :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    for(int i=0;i<array2.length;i++){
array2[i] = array1[array2.length-i];
}
```

Esto te debe permitir copiar los datos en orden inverso pruébalo y dime. es sencillo